# How to get all values in QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, tableview

I know if I want to take index and data of selected values in tableview like;

```
QModelIndexList _indexes = ui->tvDatabaseImages->selectionModel()->selectedRows();


    foreach (QModelIndex index, _indexes)
    {
        qDebug() << "TableView Index = " << QString::number(index.row());

        qDebug() << "TableView Index Value = " << index.data().toInt();
    }
```

However I want to get all tableview indexlist without selection. Is it possible? If yes, how I can do it ?

Comment: Maybe try playing with `QAbstractItemModel::match()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the model behind the `QTableView`:

```
model=myView.model()
for ( int col = 0; col < model.columnCount(); ++col ) 
  {
  for( int row = 0; row < model.rowCount(); ++row ) 
     {
     index = model.index( row, col );
     qDebug() << index.data();
     }
  }
```

Oddly, I didn't find anything more straightforward.

Comment: Ohh.. you are right I know model's colum and row count.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants QModelIndexList, they can get it by iterating over all rows of model.

```
QModelIndexList indices;
for (int i=0; i<model->rowCount(); i++){
    indices << model->indexFromItem(model->item(i, 0));
}
```

Make sure model is of "QStandardItemModel" type not "QAbstractItemModel". if your model is of QAbstractItemModel type you can cast it using static cast.

```
QStandardItemModel *currModel = static_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(model());
```